# How to rename existing folder while uploading generic artifacts to JFrog Artifactory in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am using jenkins pipeline. The folder which needs to be uploaded to Artifactory is generated in the *.tar.gz format. Everytime after Jenkins build, the folder name remains same, no change in folder name.
 For generic Artifactory integration I don't want to override the previously uploaded *tar.gz. Want to know if tar.gz can uploaded in the incremented order based number/date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can change the path where you are generating your artifacts (*.tar.gz), lets say give the path as below:-

```
$BRANCH_NAME/$BUILD_ID/*.tar.gz
```

It will upload the artifacts with the same name, but will be separated using $BRANCH_NAME/$BUILD_ID.